# Adding data to Dictonary in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I've an xml file like

```
 <Data> 
  <Element ValOne="1" Key="KeyOne" /> 
  <Element ValOne="2" Key="KeyOne" /> 
  <Element ValOne="3" Key="KeyOne" /> 
  <Element ValOne="4" Key="KeyOne" /> 
  <Element ValOne="5" Key="KeyTwo" /> 
  <Element ValOne="6" Key="KeyTwo" /> 
  <Element ValOne="7" Key="KeyThree" /> 
  <Element ValOne="8" Key="KeyThree" /> 
  <Element ValOne="9" Key="KeyThree" /> 
  <Element ValOne="10" Key="KeyThree" /> 
 </Data>
```

and a dictonary

```
 Dictionary<string, List<string>> m_dictSample = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

i need to add the data  from the file to dictonary like:

```
KeyOne       "1"
             "2"
             "3"
             "4"
KeyTwo       "5"
             "6"
KeyThree     "7"
             "8"
             "9"
            "10"
```

now i'm using like

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();


lst = (XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Sample.xml").Descendants("Element").
            Select(l_Temp => l_Temp.Attribute("Key").Value)).ToList();



 m_dictSample = (from str in lst
                        from el in XDOC.Descendants("Element")
                        where (str == el.Attribute("Key").Value)
                        select new { Key = str, value =new List<string>( el.Attribute("ValOne") }).
                      ToDictionary(l_Temp => l_Temp.Key, l_Temp => l_Temp.value);
```

but its throwing an exception like   " The best overloaded method match  for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.List(int)' has some invalid arguments

please give me a better solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a compile-time error, not an exception. Still, the answer should be easy. Writing now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for any reason you want to do it the classic way (I already built it while Jon posted his so might as well post it) here is how you could do it

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Sample.xml");

Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = (from root in document.Descendants("Element")
                                                       group root by root.Attribute("Key").Value into KeyGroup
                                                       select KeyGroup)
                                                       .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, 
                                                                     grp => grp.Attributes("ValOne").Select(at => at.Value).ToList());
```

Answer (score 3):

LINQ has built-in support for this with *lookups*:

```
m_dictSample = doc.Descendants("Element")
                  .ToLookup(element => (string) el.Attribute("Key"),
                            element => (string) el.Attribute("ValOne"));
```

Note that this will return an `ILookup<string, string>` - this isn't a `Dictionary`, but it allows you to look up a group by key, like this:

```
foreach (string value in lookup["some key"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

or

```
foreach (var group in lookup)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
    foreach (string value in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  " + value);
    }
}
```

If you *really* want a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` you could use this:

```
var dictionary = lookup.ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                                     group => group.ToList());
```